# Size of HTML Elements In Inches On High DPI Screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a web-app that has certain features that need to have consistent sizes across various devices. I am using measurements in CSS with units in inches. This works well for lower DPI screens, but when I test it on devices that have high DPI screens in which the OS scales applications, items are smaller than they are supposed to be. I was wondering if there is a way in HTML, Javascript, or CSS to fix this issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you